# $\sum a_n x^n$ converges uniformly on $[−b,b]$.

Tags: calculus

prove :

Suppose $\sum a_n x^n $has   radius of convergence $r$ (where $r$ could be $\infty$ as well). Let $b$ be any nonnegative real number with $b < r$. Then $\sum a_n x^n$ converges uniformly on $[−b,b]$.

hint : we know that $\sum |a_n b^n |$ convergence . This should be all set for the Weierstrass $M$ test

any help with that please.

Comment: thank you I know I have to use the definition of uniform convergence but I am not sure how can I use it ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: following the definition of uniform convergence you must show that for each $\epsilon>0$ exists a $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k\right|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k x^k\right|<\epsilon,\quad\forall x\in[-b,b],\forall n\ge N$$

Now use the convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_k b^k|$ to show that the above is true (check the epsilon-N definition for a convergent sequence).

Answer (score 0):

On $[-b, b]$, $ \sum \|a_nx^n\|_\infty = \sum |a_nb^n|$ is a convergent series, therefore $ \sum a_nx^n $ is normally convergent and thus uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 0):

The Weierstrass $M$-test tells us that if we have 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)$$
and, for each $n$ and each $x\in E$, there exists a positive $M_n$ such that
$$\left|f_n(x)\right|\leq M_n$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}M_n<\infty,$$
then $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly on $E$.

In your case, $E$ corresponds to $[-b,b]$, $f_n(x)=a_nx^n$, and $M_n=|a_nb^n|$. You know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}M_n<\infty$$ because $b$ is strictly less than the radius of convergence. Hence, by the Weierstrass $M$-test, you series converges uniformly on $[-b,b]$.

Comment: There's an important condition on the Weierstrass $M$-test that you must remember to consider: You must ascertain that each $M_n$ is positive--some of them could be zero, which would lead to potential nonsense when discussing $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$.

Comment: @Decaf-Math thank you for pointing that out. I know that, for $|x|\leq b$, $|a_n x^n|\leq |a_nb^n|\leq |a_nb^n|+\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon>0$. So is it enough to choose $M_n = |a_nb^n|+\epsilon$?